# InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Tags: java, selenium

I try to click on the select menu and to choose the element:

```
<div id="_desktop_currency_selector">
    <div class="currency-selector dropdown js-dropdown">
        <span>Currency:</span>
        <span class="expand-more _gray-darker hidden-sm-down" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">UAH ₴</span>
        <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="hidden-sm-down">
            <i class="material-icons expand-more"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-sm-down" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a title="EUR" rel="nofollow" href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=2" class="dropdown-item">EUR €</a>
            </li>
            <li class="current">
                <a title="UAH" rel="nofollow" href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=1" class="dropdown-item">UAH ₴</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="USD" rel="nofollow" href="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=3" class="dropdown-item">USD $</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <select class="link hidden-md-up">
            <option value="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=2">EUR €</option>
            <option value="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=1" selected="selected">UAH ₴</option>
            <option value="http://prestashop-automation.qatestlab.com.ua/ru/?SubmitCurrency=1&amp;id_currency=3">USD $</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My way:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.className("link hidden-md-up"));
Select dropList = new Select(element1);
//    debug sysout
dropList.getOptions().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getText()));
```

In result I get this exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector:
>   Compound class names not permitted

---

### How to correctly click on an element, using `selenium`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work with select class because, its not pure drop-down, its un-ordered lists of currencies

you need to open drop down by clicking on it, do something like this

```
driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='currency-selector dropdown js-dropdown']/a[@data-toggle='dropdown']")).click();
```

with this drop down list will open, now get individual element from list using xpath-

```
.//a[@title='USD']   or  .//a[@title='USD']/parent::li
```

Comment: I get a new exception (in `driver.findElement....` line): `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='currency-selector dropdown js-dropdown open']/a[@data-toggle='dropdown']"}
`

Comment: check locator, I changed locator, by mistake i had given locator for open drop down it should be for dropdown arrow it will work now, i removed word `open` from class name if you notice, also use some sleep/wait before clicking

Answer (score 2):

The exception is due to the multiple classes used in the selector. Change your selector to use single class or a cssSelector. See example below. 
Check if these selectors return unique(required) element.

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.className("hidden-md-up"));
```

OR

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".link.hidden-md-up"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get more than 1 element in the above cases. Have any other resolve?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 select element with that locator? Based on the html given, this should work - `By.cssSelector("select.link.hidden-md-up")`

Comment: I have 2 elements in the result.  Additionally, I have no result in `Select` instance: `        `Select dropList = new Select(element.get(0));
        String s = dropList.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();`